# Unable to delete certain Chrome files located in Appdata folder

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

So, the story starts with me finding nearly 20 malwares on my pc(*super sus* I know) and the consequent uninstallation of chrome(I dont use edge for anything usually)

So while other folders got deleted easily(some by restarting the pc again and again)...a specific folder and it's files sort of broke my deletion process

> The directory is *C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default*

[image: These are the black sheeps]

So, all of the files in this screenshot dont delete..Deleting them leaves the file explorer process hung in the *Calculating* stage..

[image: Stuck deletion process]

Rmdir failed upon trying..my pc got stuck after trying this..

So, is there any way that I can completely delete them??

*P.S. -  I am trying so hard so as to do a completely fresh chrome install and remove any other shady files*

*Hardware Specifications*

1. Windows 10 20H2(downgraded deliberately due to certain...issues)
2. 4Gb RAM
3. 125 Gb SSD(having the Chrome folder and my complete windows) + 500Gb WD Hard Drive

Thanks for helping

EDIT1(7/7/21)- So, well yes, I ensured no running chrome service (corroborated by me restarting the pc multiple times) and me ending chrome crash handler and update processes from the task manager.

Comment: Verify you don't have any services connected to Google Chrome running.  You can [edit] your question to include the necessary information to answer your question.

Comment: Edited and also..most files located in c drive were deleted right away..the appdata folder poses a unique problem for my previous deletion experiences ( @Ramhound is aware of the previous read-write process problems I have had...this I am unsure is or isn't a product of that)

Comment: It's time to replace your SSD.  Restarting your machine, would just restart the service responsible for keeping Chrome updated by the way.  Which is the reason my suggestion was specifically targeted towards the service(s) themselves.

Comment: _doom music plays_ I mean I am shocked.....crystaldiskinfo says it is healthy..yet, we have evidence suggesting otherwise.... _highest frustration and confusion clouds_ ...Well then.....I am still gonna wait...  _P.S. what do these files do...please tell me that is deleting them even necessary i.e. are these shady(if they aren't it will change the equation then)_  Thanks @Ramhound btw